# How to get data to according mail from database by clicking the button?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a table called admin tickets. I have this situation were one of these mails, which are on the left of the screen is clicked. Then I want to fetch subject/text, to this mail.
For example I'm clicking qweqweqwe@wp.pl, and it gives me 123123123123123.
The table looks like this:

[image]

For now the page looks like this, because I'm iterating over the whole table to the end. This looks good. The only change I want to make is as I said, I want to click the mail on the left, and get subject/text of this mail.

How can I achieve it?

[image]

Html+php:

```
<?php
require_once '../../services/LoggedInUserService.php';
require_once '../../services/LoggedInAdminService.php';
require_once '../../db/connect.php';
$connect = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DingDog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css-images/style-admintickets.css">

</head>

<body>
<header>
    <div class="row">
        <ul id="logo"><img src="../../css-images/dingdog-logo.png"></ul>

        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li style="padding-left:10px"><a href="admintickets.php">TICKETS</a></li>
            <li style="padding-left:10px" id="sign"><a href="../../services/LogoutService.php">LOG OUT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <section>
        <article>
            <p id="profilesign">Tickets:</p>
            <?php
            $result = $connect->query("SELECT emailLogin,subject,text FROM tickets");
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $emailLogin = $row['emailLogin'];
                    $subject = $row['subject']; ?>
                    <label> <input readonly id="fi" style="margin-top: 50px;" type="text" placeholder="Example"
                                   name="custom" value="<?php echo $emailLogin; ?>"></label><br>
                    <div class="container" style='position:absolute;left:0px; top:0px;'>
                        <h1 id="avatar">Title:</h1>
                        <div class="title" style='position:absolute;left:0px; top:0px;'>
                            <h1 id="tytul" style='position:absolute;left:0px; top:0px;'><?php echo $subject; ?></h1>
                        </div>
                        <h1 id="subject">Subject:</h1>
                        <textarea readonly id="subjectContainer"
                                  style='margin-top: 100px;margin-left: 150px;position:absolute;left:0; top:0;font-size:30px; color:red ;height: 264px;
  width: 683px;' rows="5" cols="10"><?php echo $row['text']; ?></textarea>
                    </div>
                <?php }
            } ?>

        </article>
    </section>
</header>
<footer>
    <img src="../../social/instagram.png"/>
    <img src="../../social/twitter-white-logo.png"/>
    <img src="../../social/facebook.png"/>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header
{
    width: 1920;
    height: 1080px;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin:0;
    height: 1080px;
    width: auto;
    background-image:  linear-gradient(180deg, #EFEFEF00 0%, #0F4A37 100%);
}

footer{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

footer img{
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.main-nav
{
    float: right;
    color: #000000;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.main-nav li
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a
{
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: Bold 25px/15px Arial;
    padding: 5px;
}

#logo
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#sign a
{
    background-color: #DCDFDE;
    padding: 30px 15px 17px 15px;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    border-right: 3px solid black;
}


#profilesign
{
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    font: Bold 57px/46px Georgia;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}

article input
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 120;
    border-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 39px;
    background-color: black;
}

#fi
{

    font: Bold 25px/12px Arial;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: 161px;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 300px;
    height: 447px;
    width: 1028px;
    background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #B4FFC5 0%, #9BCEA2 31%, #523A3A 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: 480px;
}

.title {
    margin-top: 35px;
    width: 686px;
    height: 37px;
    background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    margin-left: 145px;
}

#avatar
{
    font: Bold 25px/12px Arial;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    color: #A37373;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#tytul
{
    font: Bold 20px/24px Arial;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    color: #000000;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

#subject
{
    font: Bold 25px/12px Arial;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    color: #A37373;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.subjectContainer
{
    margin-top: 100px;
    height: 264px;
    width: 683px;
    background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #B4FFC5 0%, #9BCEA2 31%, #523A3A 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    margin-left: 170px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-top: 300px;
}

#subjectTitle
{
    text-align: left;
    font: Regular 20px/24px Arial;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#textare{
    height: 600px;
    width: 683px;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 500px){
    body {
        background-image:  linear-gradient(180deg, #EFEFEF00 0%, #0F4A37 70%);
        background-size:100% 3000px;
        width: auto;
    }
    .main-nav
    {
        float: right;
        color: #000000;
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .main-nav li a
    {
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;
        font: Bold 31px/15px Arial;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    #logo img
    {
        margin-left: 350px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 500px;
    }

    #profilesign
    {
        margin-top: 350px;
        font-size: 90px;
        margin-left: 360px;
        width: 900px;
    }

    #tytul
    {
        font: Bold 40px/24px Arial;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        color: #000000;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 25px;
    }

    #subjectText
    {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    #fi
    {
        width: 500px;
        margin-top: 500px;
        font: Bold 45px/12px Arial;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        margin-left: 401px;
    }

    .container {
        margin-top: 1000px;
        height: 847px;
        width: 1228px;
        background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #B4FFC5 0%, #9BCEA2 31%, #523A3A 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
        border-radius: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }


    .subjectContainer
    {
        margin-top: 150px;
        height: 564px;
        width: 883px;
        background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #B4FFC5 0%, #9BCEA2 31%, #523A3A 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
        border: 1px solid #707070;
        margin-left: 185px;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }

    #avatar
    {
        font: Bold 55px/12px Arial;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        color: #A37373;
        margin-top:80px;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }

    #subject
    {
        font: Bold 45px/12px Arial;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        color: #A37373;
        margin-top:80px;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }

    .title {
        margin-top: 55px;
        width: 686px;
        height: 67px;
        background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
        border: 1px solid #707070;
        margin-left: 185px;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need an ajax call that will get the data and in success response on that ajax call, you will have to set the value in the fields by accessing them with their ids

Answer (score 0):

Hope This will help you

```
<section>
        <article>
            <p id="profilesign">Tickets:</p>
            <?php
            $result = $connect->query("SELECT emailLogin,subject,text FROM tickets");
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $emailLogin = $row['emailLogin'];
                echo '<form>
                    <label> <input id="fi" style="margin-top: 50px;" type="submit" placeholder="Example"
                                   name="custom" value="'.$emailLogin.'"></label><br>
</form>';
}
}?>


<?php
if(isset($_GET['custom']))
{
$text = $_GET['custom'];
            $result2 = $connect->query("SELECT emailLogin,subject,text FROM tickets WHERE emailLogin = '".$text."' ");
            if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

echo '                    <div class="container" style="position:absolute;left:0px; top:0px;">
                        <h1 id="avatar">Title:</h1>
                        <div class="title" style="position:absolute;left:0px; top:0px;">
                            <h1 id="tytul" style="position:absolute;left:0px; top:0px;">'.$subject.'</h1>
                        </div>
                        <h1 id="subject">Subject:</h1>
                        <textarea readonly id="subjectContainer"
                                  style="margin-top: 100px;margin-left: 150px;position:absolute;left:0; top:0;font-size:30px; color:red ;height: 264px;
  width: 683px;" rows="5" cols="10">'.$row['text'].'</textarea>
                    </div>';
                                        }
             }

}
?>



        </article>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use Ajax for this, and then get the information that way. So when you click one of the mails on the left, then you make a Ajax call to another `.php`, like this.

Lets say the mail is this image.

```php
echo'<img class="MAILyouWantToAttach" data-id = "'.$MAILyouWantToAttach.'" src = "../text.png">';
```

The Ajax success respons has to change the textareas content by its value.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".Unflagging", function(){          
              var text= $(this).data("id");
                  $.ajax({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "AnotherFile.php",
                    data: { text: text},
                    success: function(data) {
                      $("#myTextarea").val(data);
                  },
                  error: function(data) {
                    alert("Error occurs!")
                 }
             });
        });
```

Then the other php file you want something like this, the echo is to print the text in the success area of the Ajax in the other `.php`.

```php
$receiver = $_POST["text"];
$result = $connect->query("SELECT emailLogin,subject,text FROM tickets WHERE emailLogin= $receiver ");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo $row['text'];
}
```

This is just a guide, but i hope it helps you on your way to success.